# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference on button click

Tags: vb.net

what would be the proper way to use the Look() from here https://code.google.com/p/tibiaapi/source/browse/trunk/tibiaapi/Objects/Item.cs

I tried making it as button like this:

```
    Public Shared Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    Item.Look()
End Sub
```

but i got this error BC30469  VB.NET Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Item is a class and Look is a non-shared method in it. Because it's not shared, you can't call Look unless you have an *instance* of the object. To make an *instance*, you use the keyword *New*. I don't know how the Item class works in particular, but in general you need to use something like this:

```
Dim myItem as New Item()
myItem.Look()
```

Comment: Don't you mean that you can't call Look? ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.